# Creating simple workflow engine with database and JAVA

Tags: java, database, workflow

For one small project, I need to create a simple approval workflow. Basically, one clicks a button, the application goes to the next approver. The questions is how to achieve this without writing any possible scenario in JAVA. What I am thinking is to have a database table, where one describe the workflow scenario and JAVA code lookups up the next steps from this table. But I can't think about the details, the table structure etc. So the bottomline is to use configuration as much as possible.

Comment: Hi, have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? jk, its really not helpful as you write only requirement without what you have tried..  you could always put a status column and start from there..

Comment: I agree, that an example would be helpful. But creating an example means that I have already some architecture or vision in my mind. But I am not. I have thought about this task for a while, but I could not find an optimal approach. The reason of posting here either to find an answer or get comments which might be helpful to find the answer.

Comment: how  complex it will be? *where one describe the workflow scenario and JAVA code lookups up the next steps from this table*. idk, but perhaps people will hesitant to put more thought on incomplete question.. flags.

Comment: When I say simple workflow, I would take as an example the following scenario. An initiator creates an application, this get approved by his direct manager, then it comes to tier 1 approver based on some critria, tie2 and tier3. Such a workflow could cover almost 100% of our needs. Now, about our options. We could buy/install BPM engine and achieve our goals, but from my perspective it is like shooting birds with a cannon, not effective, too costly.

Comment: Did you start anything on it yet? I am working on a similar thought/idea here - https://github.com/ajkr195/CaseManager may be we can connect to work on this idea..!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, is a kind of human-centric workflow engine. As you have already noticed, the possible scenarios in practice can be manifold. The reason is that there can be

- sequential flows
- forks and splits
- as also loops or cycles

The question is how a data structure must look like to describe all these scenarios? The answer here is the [OMG standard BPMN 2.0](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/). This is a descriptive way to describe a workflow. A BPMN file is simple XML and can be visualized with modeling tools like [Eclipse BPMN](https://www.eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/).

If you store this kind of XML (e.g. simply into your file system), than you can write an engine parsing this model and react in a appropriate way. 
There are workflow engines based on BPMN available, also as Open Source projects. 
Take a look at the [Imixs-Workflow project](http://www.imixs.org) which provides a open source workflow engine focusing on human centric wokflows. 
A human centric workflow engine answers the questions you have mentioned in your requirement, like:

- Who is the owner of a business task => Routing
- Who is allowed to access and modify the data => Security
- Who need to be informed => Messaging

But implementing a workflow engine is not easy either. In the end, you need a parser for the XML to answer the question 'what is the next task?'.